# How to build maven spark project (Scala), then import and config eclipse

Tags: scala, maven

I have cloned  this project: https://github.com/sryza/aas
and built successful with maven ( pom.xml)

I then import to Eclipse oxygen ( scala IDE plug in), open and run the file "main.scala", and had an error: not found the main class though I had tried to run as configuration with scala nature. Which step i missed?
In general how can i config eclipse to switch with Java, Scala, and python(install PyDev) 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1 When you clone the project use: **mvn eclipse:eclipse** so you can import it in eclipse.

2  Run **mvn clean install** to see if the project is building

[image]

Witch Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers you should be able to run it

Comment: I had built successful with maven ( pom.xml): mvn clean install, and then mvn eclipse:eclipse, then imported to eclipse. The problem is eclipse work only with Java, not with scala, python...thanks

Comment: If you have Eclipse for Java EE Developers you should be able to run it. Which eclipse do you use?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers I think
http://www.eclipse.org/oxygen/
I didn't pay attention when download eclipse
Should I remove and reinstall Eclipse for Java EE Developers, thanks

Comment: Yeah, replace the eclipse version

Comment: I replaced it, now I use eclipse prebuild with Scala IDE 4.7.0 with scala 2.12.  I then rebuild  project successful with maven then imported to eclipse, it show errors: scala version? How I fix it, had tried alot? thanks Kire

Comment: @ Kire: I found very clear answer in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aB4-RD_MMf0